# Foundation and Compass Config Error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, zurb-foundation

I've Googled around and can’t find anything:

I've installed the `zurb-foundation` and `compass` gems, but when I try to create a new project I get the following error:

```
LoadError on line 45 of /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: no such file to load -- zurb-foundation
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

I think this is because it's looking in the wrong place, the gem installed in the ruby 2.0 directory, and `ruby -v` returns `ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]`

Also, `which ruby` points to the 2.0 executable.

How do I tell compass to look in the right place? I can't seem to find a global config file.

Sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems there was just too many versions of Ruby installed at different times on my system.

After adding the following to the top of my `/etc/paths`, the problem was resolved:

```
/Users/n/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/bin
/Users/n/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems
/Users/n/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
```

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, that’s one Ruby (line 1), one path for gem executables (line 2), and an alternate path for gem executables (line 3)...

Comment: Oh no, sorry, I meant "same problem here and it was resolved by cleaning the PATH".

Comment: Really dumb question but where/how do you change the paths?